# retrieve wallpaper system setting in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I would like to retrieve iphone wallpaper system setting and display the system wallpaper into my iphone app as background image. Is it possible or sample code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Year later, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are *no* documented procedures to get the wallpaper image, but you may use these *undocumented* methods (usual warnings apply):

- `+[UIImage defaultDesktopImage]`.
- Read the image at `/var/mobile/Library/LockBackground.jpg`.

Comment: @Petesh: Not really, you can access it indirectly by symlink-ing to it.

Comment: I did not know that. Consider me educated... goes off and writes test application...

Comment: I get a NULL file when I try to access the lock background image via a symlink. defaultDesktopImage returns the globe image, not the current desktop image.

Comment: @Petesh: Hm maybe the sandbox is tightened.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kenny. Those two approaches can not work properly. 1.`[UIImage defaultDesktopImage]` can only return the fixed image which is always "Earth" image. If I select other image in the wallpaper folder, it still returns the "Earth" image. 2. I use UIImage `imageWithContentsOfFile` method to load @"/var/mobile/Library/LockBackground.jpg" or @"/User/Library/LockBackground.jpg" or @"/User/Library/LockBackground.png" The image is always nil. Do you know why? Thanks again.